# Using 'like' in SSRS parameter check

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to show or hide column when the value has the word 'decease' from the parameter values (parameter name is `FILTERBYand` it contains multiple values). I'm trying to use the expression:

```
=IIf(Parameters!FILTERBY.Value like "*decease*",False,True)
```

This is not working. The `FILTERBY` parameter is a text datatype and **Allow Multiple values** option is enabled. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If allow multiple parameters is set, you should expect that the parameter `FILTERBY` is an array of values. In such a case you should use the Join or String.Join function to make a string out of the parameter values array, and then check if it contains the string.

Try the following:

```
IIF(InStr(Join(Parameters!FILTERBY.Value,","),"decease")>0, False, True)
```

or to better suite the question

```
IIF(Join(Parameters!FILTERBY.Value,",") like "*decease*", False, True)
```

Comment: The given answer not worked but it gives me an idea to achieve. Instead of receiving all the values in single parameter, I created multiple parameters for the available values. Using below IIF condition, I resolved the issue. IIF(InStr(Join(Parameters!Decease.Value,","),"")>0, False, True)